# Bluetooth Connection messes up all music apps

Tags: bluetooth

I bought an iFox Bluetooth Shower Speaker, and paired it with my Windows Phone.

As soon as I connect, the following things happen:

1. Pandora opens, and skips songs continuously as if someone accidentally kept pressing that button.
2. Music app crashes.
3. Spotify plays the song, but stops the play immediately.
4. The mic on Cortana's page never initiates Cortana.
5. When I make a call, my phone chooses 'Speaker' automatically and I am unable to hear anything.

It looks like a bug to me. My MAC connects to the speaker properly. My Windows Phone connects to other bluetooth speakers and devices properly.

Is there anything I can do, of course apart from returning the speaker?

Answer (score 1):

Well if your Windows Phone connects to other speakers properly you'll have to go with another speaker. I assume your speaker send invalid and/or unintentional commands to your phone through bluetooth.